# Comparing a string with a list of strings to find anagrams in Python

Tags: python, string, function

I am trying to work out how to compare a string (str1) with a list of strings (str_list), and then return a list of all the strings in str_list that are anagrams of str1.

I have previously defined a function to compare two strings and print True if they are anagrams of each other, and False if not.

```
def anagram(str1,str2):
      if sorted(str1) == sorted(str2):
             print (True)
      else:
             print (False)
```

I have attempted to start to define the next function but I'm struggling to return the list of strings that are anagrams.

```
def find_anagrams_in_word_list(str1, str_list):
     str_list = [] #assumed an empty list has to be made first
     str_list = input
     if sorted(str1) in sorted(str_list):
           #return strings that are anagrams
```

Not sure if this is how I'm meant to do it as I'm still a beginner, so any pointers would be very helpful!

Thanks.

Comment: Just a side note.. but writing something like if x: print(True) else: print(False) is exacly the same as print(x). In your case just write print(sorted(str1) == sorted(str2))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The faster way to do this would be to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
def isAnagram(str1, str2):
    return Counter(str1) == Counter(str2)

def find_anagrams_in_word_list(str1, str_list):
    return [word for word in str_list if isAnagram(str1, word)]
```

Note that your `isAnagram` will not behave as you expect because you only `print` the value, you do not `return` it. For you to be able to use your `isAnagram` function, as I did in my above list comprehension for example, you'd have to do one of the following.

```
def anagram(str1,str2):
    if sorted(str1) == sorted(str2):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Or more concisely

```
def anagram(str1,str2):
    return sorted(str1) == sorted(str2):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generators for that , Also note that the result of `sorted` function is a list and you need to convert it to string with `''.join()` and then compare :

```
def find_anagrams_in_word_list(str1, str_list):
     return [ i for i in str_list if ''.join(sorted(str1)) == ''.join(sorted(i))]
```

Demo :

```
>>> l =['abcd', 'msnd']
>>> find_anagrams_in_word_list('cba',l)
['abcd']
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  You set the input list to empty for some reason, then you set it to a function, and then you try to iterate over it.  `''.join(sorted(str1)) in ''.join(sorted(i))` isn't a valid anagram test anyway, because `'abc'` is in `'abcd'` but they're not anagrams.

Comment: This will not produce the correct result. As @DSM said, it will include substrings of the original word, which are not valid anagrams.

Comment: @Cyber i think i have a miss understanding about anagrams ! can you explain ?

Comment: @Kasra Here is an example of an anagram: "rose" and "sore". They have the same letters in a different order. "ore" and "sore" are NOT anagrams, one is simply a subset of the other.

Comment: oops , thanks , i just need to change `in` with `==` thanks @Cyber!